# Missing Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, scaffolding, .net-7.0

I know that there are some similar issues here with older versions. But none of the solutions proposed there seems to work. Scaffolding just went away out of the blue. No updates, no upgrades were performed.

I am targeting .net-7, and obviously, I have .NET SDKs installed: 7.0.203 (latest), which contains .NET Runtime 7.0.5 and ASP.NET Core Runtime 7.0.5.

- I have removed and reinstalled both this and ef core packages bot globally and locally.
- I have tried Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 7.0.6 (latest) and 7.0.5 to match EF Core version.
- I have cleaned the package cache
- I have removed .vs folder

the result is the same:

```
PM>  dotnet aspnet-codegenerator --help
....
No code generators are available in this project. Add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design package to the project as a NuGet package reference.

PM> dotnet list package | select-string Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design

   > Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design         7.0.5       7.0.5
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Sometimes visual studio can be funny. Try restarting your PC.  
Clean solution and Rebuild. Open the Dependency on the Solution explorer and look for the package. CHeck if there is a package folder in the Solution Directory to see if the package is there.

Comment: It is in dependencies, it is in .csproj and it is in "~home/nuget/packages". No project local packages folder exists, all the other dependencies are also referenced from that cache. I will try restarting everything as suggested.

Comment: Did not help :(

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I had same issue today and it go away when I installed `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc` first and then `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` and then
`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design`, installing design packages before MVC seems to break it permanently (I couldn't fix one of my project showing same error even though I cleared everything in bin, obj and project files and install them in above order. 
Seems more people are having [same issue](https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/2014)

Comment: @AaA Sorry, nope.. :(